# How can we tell if a plugin was installed from the logs in Confluence?

Tags: logging, plugins, confluence

We have a server instance of Confluence. I know how to validate which current plugins are installed in the interface, but I would like to know how to find when a plugin was installed from the log files.

I have looked through past logs and do not easily find any, but the goal is to audit the logs automatically to identify if there are any changes. What would be the lines to look for?

Note: I know that I could install a new plugin and go check the log to see what was written to it, but this is not possible at the moment.